Circular logic in a proof, can't prove or disprove an assertion at all.

$\forall$ $a$, $n$ $\in \mathbb Z$, if $a|n^2$ and $a\le n$, then $a|n$.

I've tried:-
From
$
∣

^
2$
: Since
$
∣
^2$, we can write:
$n
^ 
2
 =ak$,
for some integer
$$.
Assuming $ =


+
$
: For integers
$$
and
$$
where $0 ≤  < $ . This means we can express $$ in terms of $$:
$ =


+
$
Squaring
$$
:
$$^2=(


+

)
^2=

^
2
^
2
+
2



+
^
2$$
$$\implies a^2+2aqr+r^2=ak$$
$$\implies a^2+2aqr+r^2-ak=0$$
$\therefore r^2\text{ mod }a=0$
I've to prove that $r\text{ mod }a=0$, and I'm back to where I started.
I've tried to prove this with the unique factorization theorem as well, but I can't find the right statements at all. The assertion seems simple, but I can't prove it at all.

Though $(-4)\mid 2^2$, $-4 \le 2$, and $(-4) \not\mid 2$.

For just positive $a$ and $n$, consider $a=4=2^2$ and $n=6=2\times 3$.

The positive counterexample comes from your attempt, by picking $r=2$, $a=4$ to satisfy both $r^2\bmod a = 0$ and $r\bmod a \ne 0$, with $n = a1+r = 6$.

I think $a$ should be a prime number for the statement to hold. If that is indeed the case, then you can prove it by writing the prime factorization of $n$.

If we assume $a$ is a prime, OP's proof works. The key argument at the end would be that $r^2 \equiv 0 \pmod a$ implies $r =0$ since $\mathbb{Z}_{a}^{\times}$ is a field. If $a$ is not a prime, as others already have pointed out, the result is simply false.

@MathGuy Note that if $a$ is required to be a prime number, then the $a\le n$ condition is not required. Also, we can basically just use Euclid's lemma to prove that $a\mid n$ rather than the prime factorization of $n$.

You used the following reduction $,a\mid nk\iff a\mid (n\bmod a)k,$ to reduce to the case $,n< a,,$ where, next, we can similarly reduce via $:!\ a\mid nk\iff a\mid (a\bmod n)k.,$ Now, if $(a,n)=1,,$ the last reduction will continually reduce $n$ to a nonzero value, so will eventually reach $,n=1,,$ which yields a proof of Euclid's Lemma $,(a,n)=1,, a\mid nk\Rightarrow a\mid k.,$ See the linked dupe for further details, including a constructive interpretation (Gauss's Lemma). $\ \  $

The prior method fails if $(a,n)>1$ in which case there are easy counterexamples. $\ \ $

Generally $\ a\mid nk\iff a\mid (a,n)k\iff  a/(a,n)\mid k\ \ $

@peterwhy, how do you find counterexamples so easily? I can't find the right one at all and get stuck at proofs.

@huh what do you mean by:-r^2≡0(mod a) implies r=0 since Z×a is a field

@Vince don't worry, such observations will strike you as you practise more. As a general strategy, if proving a statement to be true seems difficult, then try to search for a counter example.

@Vince, I referred to $\mathbb{Z}_a^{\times}$ as a field for convenience, but you don't need to consider the full assertion. The point is that when $a$ is a prime number, the residue system ${1, \ldots, a-1}$ contains no zero divisors. This means that if you have an equation of the form $x y \equiv 0 \pmod{a}$, then either $x \equiv 0 \pmod{a}$ or $y \equiv 0 \pmod{a}$. It is not difficult to prove this and you can apply it directly to your question (again, only when $a$ is a prime).
